# Fullcalendar - Need event to not be more than a day - using selectAllow but issue with allDay

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-3

I'm using Fullcalendar and need events to not be more than a day.

I've got it working for when you pick an hour range but it never works for allDay events, as the from and to dates are different.  Here is my selectAllow function.  I'm aware it's not elegant, my Javascript is limited!

```
function(selectInfo) { 
    var ambig = selectInfo.start._ambigTime;
    var from_date = selectInfo.start._d;
    from_date = String(from_date).substr(0, 10);
    var to_date = selectInfo.end._d;
    to_date = String(to_date).substr(0, 10);

    if (from_date != to_date)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
    var duration = moment.duration(selectInfo.end.diff(selectInfo.start));
    console.log(duration.asHours());
}
```

As you can see from the code, I've gone down the route of having different checks based on ambigTime (I assume this is whether it's allDay or not?) and using the duration but the duration doesn't work when it's all day.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: "not more than a day". Do you mean a) the event must not be greater than 24hrs in duration (regardless of exactly when it starts and ends), or b) the event must not cross the midnight boundary between 2 different days (regardless of its total duration), or c) something else? It's a bit unclear. And what does "doesn't work" mean precisely? What exactly goes wrong compared to what you expected?

Comment: P.S. Why are you relying on `_d` and string comparisons when momentJS has lots of date comparison functions built in which you could use to directly compare the start and end values? See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/ . Of course there is also diff() which you seem to have already discovered.

Comment: P.P.S. a worked example would probably help us to understand the different cases you're trying to deal with. I made a runnable demo of your code just to make it easier to try things out: http://jsfiddle.net/sc78wb0k/ . I noticed that removing the `if` block allows it to go through to the duration test in all cases, and that the duration will be logged as 24 hours when trying to select an all-day slot: http://jsfiddle.net/sc78wb0k/1/ . Doesn't that meet your requirement? I guess it depends on whether your requirement is option a or b, as per my first comment.

Comment: It's not 24 hours, it whether something goes through a day of the week, so if the start is on Wednesday, you can't finish it on Thursday.  RE removing the if, returning false is the thing that stops an event being allowed and the return is in the if.  Thanks for the fiddle and to use moment, I had already looked at this a little, I'll look at it more in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can solve this much more neatly and simply by using [selectConstraint](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/selectConstraint). This limits the user's selection to a certain window of time. By specifying it as per the following example, it effectively limits an individual selection to the day where the selection began:

```
selectConstraint: {
  start: '00:00', 
  end: '24:00', 
},
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9qv5xz18/

Comment: Brilliant!!  I had passed by this in the documentation and thought it wasn't what I needed.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ADyson, I've fixed it.  I think I can neaten up the code but the below now works.

```
function(selectInfo) {
    console.log(selectInfo);
      var ambig = selectInfo.start._ambigTime;
      var from_date = selectInfo.start._d;
      var from_dat = selectInfo.start;
      var to_dat = selectInfo.end;

      console.log(to_dat.diff(from_dat))

      from_date = String(from_date).substr(0, 10);
      var to_date = selectInfo.end._d;
      to_date = String(to_date).substr(0, 10);

      if (!ambig)
      {
      if (from_date != to_date) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
      }
      else
      {
        return to_dat.diff(from_dat) == 86400000;
      }
      var duration = moment.duration(selectInfo.end.diff(selectInfo.start));
      console.log(duration.asHours());
}
```

Comment: N.B. you don't need to reply on the internal `_ambig` property here. fullCalendar v3 extends moment and provides a public `hasTime()` function to indicate this status. That would be the proper way to call it. See  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/moment . And you still shouldn't rely on string output of dates - this can vary by browser and timezone, culture etc. momentJS provides ways to get the individual parts of the date, or to format it all. But anyway I found a much simpler and more reliable way to implement your requirement - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57789718/5947043)